# Add text with different style to a existing label

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label with text and want to add more test in running time, but I want to add different style to this text that was add. Is there a way to do this?

This is the code

```
label.text = (label.text ?? "") + " \n  \(userName)"
```

How do I add style to `userName` without changing the style of the label?

Comment: Your Answer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring

Comment: Your Question Not Clear Can you Explain it with an example ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use attributed text in UILabel:

here some code.

a) some useful typedefs:

```
typealias AttrDict = [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
```

a) create some styles:

```
func textAttribute() -> AttrDict{
    let textFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32)
    let stdAttrib = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
                     //NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle2,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red] as AttrDict
    return stdAttrib
}

func smallTextAttribute() -> AttrDict{
    let textFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    let stdAttrib = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green] as AttrDict

    return stdAttrib
}
```

c) build Your attributed String:

```
func myAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString {
let pieces = ["hello", "word"]

let resultAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString()
var s = ""

s = pieces[0] + "\n"
resultAttributed.append(NSAttributedString(string: s,
                                           attributes: stdTextAttribute() ))

s = pieces[1] + "\n"
resultAttributed.append(NSAttributedString(string: s,
                                           attributes: smallTextAttribute() ))


return resultAttributed
```

}

d) put in Your label/textView:

....

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    myLabel.attributedText = myAttributedString()
}
```

}

I made a GIST:

https://gist.github.com/ingconti/aefc78c6d0b22f5329f906094c312a21

PLS connect UIlabel..
:)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to use NSMutableAttributedString, NSAttributedString and use label.attributedText, How?

Doing this:

```
let userName = "StackOverflow"
    let prefixText = NSAttributedString(string: "this is normal ")
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: font,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
    ]
    let userNameWithStyle = NSAttributedString(string: userName, attributes: attributes)

    let finalString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: prefixText)
    finalString.append(userNameWithStyle)
    self.label.attributedText = finalString
```

[Image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Loocr.png)